# do..while(0) function-like C macro wrapper in c2hs

Tags: c, haskell, c-preprocessor, petsc, c2hs

I'd like to wrap a function-like C macro in a C function (and in turn wrap it in Haskell with a `{#fun ... #}` block), but the `c2hs` preprocessor chokes on the `do.. while(0)` syntax; 
here's the code:

```
module TestMacro where
#c

#define TestF1(n) do{if n==0 return 0;else return 1; } while(0)

int c_testF1(int x)
{ return ( TestF1(x) ); }

#endc
```

and here's the error:

```
c2hs TestMacro.chs
c2hs: C header contains errors:

TestMacro.chs.h:6: (column 12) [ERROR]  >>> Syntax error !
  The symbol `do' does not fit here.

make: *** [main] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong? 
My goal is wrapping the `CHKERRQ` macro of the PETSc library, defined as follows in `petscerror.h`(split onto multiple lines for readability):

```
#define CHKERRQ(n)             
    do {if (PetscUnlikely(n)) 
        return PetscError(PETSC_COMM_SELF,__LINE__,PETSC_FUNCTION_NAME,__FILE__,n,PETSC_ERROR_REPEAT," ");} 
    while (0)
```

Comment: The definition of `CHKERRQ` misses the `\\` at its line-ends.

Comment: I feel coding a `return` statement in a marco makes the code using it unreadable and with this unmaintainable, ugly, ... - all in all a bad thing.

Comment: CHKERRQ is a logger utility in a large library, can't do much about it ..

Comment: As it stands CHKERRQ wont't "compile".

Comment: It does not compile within this small example, no. But it certainly does when the PETSc headers are linked. But perhaps I haven't understood your remark..?

Comment: "Multiline"-macro need to carry a trailing \ at every line's end (but the last). Those \ are mising in the code you show.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that `#define` is  text replacement. So

```
{ return ( TestF1(c) ); }
```

becomes

```
{ return ( do{if c==0 return 0;else return 1; } while(0) ); }
```

and you can neither use `do { .. } while()` nor other `return` statements as return parameters (and the brackets around the `ìf` - condition are missing). For your macro to work at that place it could be simply defined as

```
#define TestF1(n)    ((n)==0 ? 0 : 1)
```

**Edit**

A function that uses `CHKERRQ` could look like this

```
int my_chkerrq( int n )
{
     CHKERRQ(n);
     return( whatever_you_want_to_return_here );
}
```

but I would suggest to directly call what `CHKERRQ()` calls:

```
int my_chkerrq( int n )
{
     if (PetscUnlikely(n)) 
         return( PetscError(PETSC_COMM_SELF,__LINE__,PETSC_FUNCTION_NAME,__FILE__,n,PETSC_ERROR_REPEAT," ") );
     else 
         return( whatever_you_want_to_return_here );
}
```

Of course, in both cases `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are replaced by those of the C code and may not be very useful in the Haskell environment

Comment: ...with emphasis on the fact that the original version's `return` *does not return from the macro*, it jumps out of the function containing the macro; the second one (with `?:`) is the one to use in general for a macro that evaluates to a value. (the definition of `TestF1` makes it look like this is a point of confusion here)

Answer (score 5):

```
{ return ( TestF1(c) ); }
```

The syntax of `return` requires an (optional) expression: you cannot use a statement instead of the expression. The `do {} while (0)` is a statement.

> (C11, 6.8.6 Jump statements)
>
> Syntax
>
> return expression_opt ;

What you can do is to use instead:

```
int c_testF1(int x)
{ TestF1(c); }
```

As I put in the comments this would work but I won't advise to do that, it is bad coding style. The `?:` could be used in the example `TestF1` macro (as written in another answer) but it cannot be used for your `CHKERRQ` real use case (you can use a macro for the `PetscError` function call though).

Comment: OP probably just wants `int c_testF1(int x) {  TestF1(c); }`.

Comment: @rampion yes, I add it in the answer

Comment: Do you feel putting a return statement in a macro is advisable coding?

Comment: @alk no I feel it's a bad coding style as it alters the grammar of the language, I won't do this personally.

Comment: My TestF1() was artificial, but CHKERRQ() is used for logging errors, given their integer code.